# setting proper permissions

Tags: linux, security, permissions, filesystems, file-permissions

I just read up on setting up user privileges for different kinds of users. Id like to create a scenario where a user can ssh into the system but can create(write) files only in /tmp. Write access should not be allowed anywhere else. Also, he should not be able to view another users files within /tmp, let alone delete them.

I believe I can accomplish the second half of the task by removing read and execute permission  of /tmp and setting the sticky bit.

However how would i go about removing the users write access from the rest of the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Id like to create a scenario where a user can ssh into the system but can create(write) files only in /tmp. Write access should not be allowed anywhere else.

In a standard Linux installation, users can write only to `/tmp` and their home directories. So you can achieve this by making a user's `$HOME` read-only and owned by root.

> Also, he should not be able to view another users files within /tmp, let alone delete them.

Give all users a restrictive umask (such as `077`) through `pam_umask`, and *set* the sticky bit on `/tmp`.

Also, play with `pam_namespace` - you can give each user his own `/tmp`.

> I believe I can accomplish the second half of the task by removing read and execute permission of /tmp and setting the sticky bit.

Incorrect. Without execute permissions on `/tmp`, the user won't be able to access or create *anything* in that directory. Without the sticky bit, anyone who can write to `/tmp` will be allowed to remove anyone's files.

> However how would i go about removing the users write access from the rest of the system?

They don't *have* write access by default. See top of this answer.